# mysql: serializing an associative array

Tags: php, mysql, serialization

I'm having an associative array, what's the easiest way to put it into db (mysql)? I mean to searialize and put in into SINGLE field. Note that after serialization I'll need to able to deserialize field.

Comment: What do you mean "single fields"? (Note your own plural). You want a single field for each member of the array? That would depend on the structure of the database and the structure of the array. Or did you mean "a single field"? What's the point of having a relational database if you store your data in a way that can't benefit from that?

Comment: That's a mistake! sorry. I want to put the whole array into one field!

Comment: I would suggest you to use TEXT as your field for serialized data.
If you know length of your serialized data you can adjust it with this info:

`TEXT will get you 65535 chars. MEDIUMTEXT will do up to 16777215. LONGTEXT will do 4294967295.`

And for deserialize use http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php

Answer (score 2):

Something like this.

```
$arr=array("data","more data");
$result=mysql_real_escape_string(serialize($arr));
mysql_query("INSERT INTO table (serialized) VALUES ('{$result}')");
```

Comment: Thank you! And how I'll deserialize? Is `mysql_real_escape_string` reverted?

Comment: using unserialize() I believe. It will return an array of strings (your serialized data)